# Cross compiling php

Tags: php, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile php for arm and have good progress but I'm totally stuck where it wants to run the php itself (have no idea why). as it is an arm binary and not intel (my building platform) it won't run:

```
/bin/sh: /path-to-build/sapi/cli/php: cannot execute binary file
```

How can I fix this? The configure script understood I'm cross compiling but didn't do anything about it (from configure log):

```
checking whether the C compiler (/path-to-compiler/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc) is a cross-compiler... yes
```

I'm compiling `php-5.3.6` with configure command line:

```
export CC=/path-to-cc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
../configure --prefix=/prefix-path/ --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi
             --disable-libxml --disable-dom --disable-openssl
             --without-iconv --without-openssl --disable-simplexml
             --disable-xml --disable-xmlreader --disable-xmlwriter
             --without-pear --without-sqlite --without-sqlite3
             --disable-pdo --without-pdo-sqlite
```

Comment: i would put the toolchain in the path, just not set `CC` then specifying `--host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi` should let `configure` find everything needed: compiler, linker, strip etc.

Comment: it doesn't matter... it fails on php, not on tools

Comment: are you sure it links correctly? what i meant was it's not because CC is arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc that `configure` resolves other toolchain's tools properly... "cannot execute binary file" can denote a linking problem because `configure` didn't use the proper linker (because you didn't set `LD`)

Comment: @Gregory Pakosz: it didn't use ld at all, it passed a switch to cc that called the linker. `cannot execute binary file` is because I'm compiling for `arm`. it tried to run php on the building machine which cannot run `arm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve this my own by disabling `phar`. I hope disabling so much modules won't break something internal.

Comment: Is there anywhere you can explain how you completed this process, in whole? I am trying to do the same thing right now and am having great difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

Build without cross compiling and then, when cross compiling, point to the host version of php by overrididing a variable in the makefile on the command line when running make.

Something like:

```
make PHP_VAR_NAME=path to php built for host
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to compile PHP for arm with the following parameters:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/toolchains/gnu_cortex-a9_tools/usr/bin" 
export ARCH=arm
```

configure script:

```
./configure --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi --prefix=/usr/arm CC="arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc --sysroot=/toolchains/gnu_cortex-a9_tools/"  --disable-libxml --disable-dom  --without-iconv --without-openssl --disable-simplexml --disable-xml --disable-xmlreader --disable-xmlwriter --without-pear --without-sqlite3 --disable-pdo --without-pdo-sqlite --disable-phar
```

followed by

```
make
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve similar issue while cross-compiling PHP 5.6.0 by editing `Makefile` after running `configure` script. Just replace all occurrences of

> $(top_builddir)/$(SAPI_CLI_PATH)

with

> /usr/bin/php

Where `/usr/bin/php` is your host php cli. Make sure it is installed, e.g., `sudo apt-get install php5-cli` for Debian/Ubuntu.

After doing so phar extension builds fine